# Will similar Strings in HashMap lead to increased chance of collisions?

Tags: java, hashmap, hash-collision, string-hashing

Consider the following:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
final String prefix = "My objects ";
int counter = 0;

void put(Object value) {
    hm.put(prefix+(counter++), value);
}
```

Given that the key of each entry starts with the same string and only differs by a number appended to it, is this likely to lead to more collisions? I'm trying to decide whether this way of creating unique keys is a good idea from a performance perspective.

Comment: Why not just use an Integer key?

Comment: No.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--

Comment: The common prefix isn't going to hurt, but converting the integers to strings...might.

Comment: @Eran Fair point, but this is just a minimal example, I need the key to be a String for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not. And that is not *necessarily* because of `String#hashcode`; but because a `HashMap` will re-hash whatever your hashcode is by XOR-ing firs 16 bits with the last 16.

```
// this is re-hashing that is done internally
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

But even if that *would* increase collision, you might never feel it.
For small buckets/bin where entries are placed one after another (in a linked fashion), `equals` will be called to get the *actual* entry you care about.

In case a certain bin/bucket reaches a certain threshold, it will be transformed in a `perfectly balanced tree node`. The search time in such a tree is `0(logn)`.

*Even* if the same entries report the same hashcode *after* the re-hash, a map has still to decide which entry is *bigger* in case of a tie.

It would then try to invoke `Comparable#compareTo` in case your Keys implement Comparable. In case they do not implement `Comparable`, `System.identityHashcode` will be called to decide in case of a tie.

As you say from a performance perspective because of all these internal things, your average search time will be `O(1)` in the Map.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Thanks!